# Three dice are simultaneously rolled, getting a number on a die greater than the sum of the numbers on the remaining two

Tags: probability, combinatorics, dice

If we throw 3 dice and we are asked the probability of having a number greater than the sum of the other two, the value of the first dice would be between 6 and 3, the other two dice will take lower values. My question is if we get a combination (6,2,3) should we also count (6,3,2) as a possibility?

Comment: Yes: in reality the three dice are distinct and (assuming these are fair independent dice) you have $6^3=216$ equally likely combinations of rolls where $(6,2,3)$ and $(6,3,2)$ are distinct outcomes

Comment: You have 3 dice. Consider you have blue, red, and yellow dice. Always, for all exercices.

Comment: A technicality that I hope you haven't missed: you mentioned "greater than", but $6\not\ge 2\times 3$